# Hadoop, directories on different volumes

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have an hadoop cluster, I would like to put a set hadoop directories on a specific set of disks (some directories in fast disk and some other directories on slow disks).
How can I achive this target?
Should I use the archival storage policies in order to move some folder on a specified directory marked as disk or archive?
Of should I use other features?
Thanks a lot.
Bye

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to tag different storage types like so in `hdfs-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
  <value>[DISK]/path/to/slow,[SSD]/path/to/fast</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Thanks, but is this the only method to put hdfs directory on different disk set? Can I only use the storage policies after set what you report? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is the only property to define DFS volumes and storage types, yes